# Rails CollectiveIdea Audit i18n

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, audit, i18n-gem

I'm using https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited in order to get my app audits.
But my entity names still on english, all my app is i18ned. Couldnt found any info in the docs. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're talking about your model names and attributes, take a look at the Rails Guide for more info :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: Exactly, this approach its better, i tried to do this in the gem.